# Moving from OSM to MapBox how do I get tiles that look similar to OSM/Google from a out of the box tileset?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I am hitting the OSM 418 I am a teapot rate limit, and want to use a different base map provider. An option I am attempting to move to is MapBox, however I am stuck with a very ugly map and I have no idea what I have done wrong.

Here is an example of a MapBox map I would like: https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/geocoding/

[image]

However when I use the following URL:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=
```

I am getting very ugly tiles:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/14/15069/9834.png?access_token=
```

[image]

Any tips on how to fix this, and/or what search terms should I be using to find the answer?

Comment: Which library do you use for map display: OpenLayers, Leaflet, ...?

Comment: @TomazicM I am using leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Mapbox had useful raster street layer, which is not the case any more as you have discovered. You have to use Mapbox vector layers. This can be done with the help of [Mapbox GL Leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) plugin.

The code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebGL</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.2.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl-leaflet/0.0.16/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40.668562, -73.906016], 15);
  
  var gl = L.mapboxGL({
      accessToken: 'your access token',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12'
  }).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

gives layer as you want it:

[image]